# Using object as _id in MongoDb causes collscan on queries

Tags: mongodb

I'm having some issues with using a custom object as my `_id` value in MongoDb.

The objects I'm storing in _id looks like this:

```
"_id" : {
    "EDIEL" : "1010101010101",
    "StartDateTicks" : NumberLong(636081120000000000)
}
```

Now, when I'm performing the following query:

```
.find({ 
        "_id.EDIEL": { $eq: "1010101010101" }, 
        "_id.StartDateTicks": { $gte: 636082776000000000, $lt: 636108696000000000 } 
}).explain()
```

I does a `COLLSCAN`. I can't figure out why exactly. Is it because I'm not querying against the `_id` object *with* an object?

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? :-)

**Edit:**

Tried to create a compound index containing the `EDIEL` and `StartDateTicks` fields, ran the query again and now it uses the index instead of a column scan. While this works, it would still be nice to avoid having the extra index and just having the _id (since it's basically a "free" index) So, the question still stands: why can't I query against the `_id.EDIEL` and `_id.StartDateTicks` and make use of the index?

Comment: Is your question like what causing COLLSCAN? and your suspicion is on custom _ID? If yes, then you were guessing it wrong because you called .explain() method which in turn performs COLLSCAN. please refer here https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/explain-results/

Comment: You will need to index the two fields separately, since indexes cant be on embedded documents.

Comment: Thanks @hyades, that's exactly the answer I needed :-) If you make an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are used on keys and not on objects, so when you use object for _id, the indexing on object can't be used for the specific query you do on the field of the object.

This is true not only for _id but subdocument also.

```
{
 "name":"awesome book",
 "detail" :{
   "pages":375,
   "alias" : "AB"
 }
}
```

Now when you have index on detail and you query by detail.pages or detail.alias, the index on detail cannot be used and certainly not for range queries. You need to have indexes on detail.pages and detail.alias.

when index is applied on object it maintains the index of object as a whole and not per field, that's why queries on object fields are not able to use object indexes.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You will need to index the two fields separately, since indexes cant be on embedded documents. Thus creating a compound index is the only option available, or creating multiple indexes on the fields which in turn use intersection index are the options for you.